# Active virtualenv is not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

Im using Python2.7.8 and virtualenv 12.0.7

i activate my virtualenv and run `which pip` but it still says `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

looks my virtualenv is active.

```
(my-env)erkans-MacBook-Air:Projects erkan$
```

if i run `python manage.py runserver` when my virtualenv is active, it says

> No module named django.core.management

django module not found because active virtualenv is not working. But i dont understand why ?

Comment: I assume you tried deactivating and reactivating then trying again?

Comment: @Holloway i tried but no solution. if i install a package while my-env active it installed in global pip list. im not using sudo command.

Comment: Could you paste output of the python command `>>> import sys; print sys.path` ?

Comment: How do you activate the venv? Can you dump the contents of the activate file for us to see?

Comment: what is your OSX version?

Answer (score 1):

1. install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper : `pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`
2. create a folder `.virtualenvs` in your home folder : `mkdir ~/.virtualenvs`. This folder will store your virtual environments
3. Add this to your `~/.bash_profile` file :

```shell
# Replace by the path of your python bin folder
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/
# Replace by the path of your python executable script that virtualenvwrapper will use
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
# Replace by the path of your virtualenvwrapper.sh file
source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

4. Restart your MacBook Air
5. Create a virtual env : `mkvirtualenv stack`
6. Activte it : `workon stack`

and now `which pip` should output this : `.virtualenvs/stack/bin/pip`

Comment: I remove all virtualenvs folder and recreate. then i activete virtualenv now which pip command  point to correct directory but still use global pip. How  i check virtualenv pip path correctly ?

Comment: it output this `.virtualenvs/stack/bin/pip`?

Comment: this is output for which pip  --> /home/user/virtualenvs/my-project/bin/pip

Comment: but ım getting no module named django. i can see in pip list Django (1.7.7)

Comment: activate your virtualenv and run : `pip install Jinja2`. Now check that the package has been installed in your virtual env. It should be in `.virtualenvs/stack/lib/python-x.x/site-packages/`

Comment: ok i installed package and it is in correct path as you told.

Comment: So it's works. now install Django and other package needed :)

Comment: i already have django package. The problem is not work in virtualenv.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95053/discussion-between-louis-barranqueiro-and-erkan-demir).

Comment: You have maybe the django package in global but not in your virtual env, that why It raise this error. If your virtualenv wasn't working, you will not be able to use the pip installed in it.